# How to set up Firebase firestore security to a collection per user/group?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I plan to have a (sub-)collection of Firestore db documents per user (I'm also using firebase auth) in my Javascript web app. How do I set up Firestore security rules so each user can only see her own docs? (But admin users can see all)

Actually my real use case a little more complicated, since I want all users who are part of group X to be able to access group X's documents. So I think I need to be able to do a db query on the group somehow.

Comment: Your question lacks enough detail to give specific advice.  Have you read the documentation about using security rules?  https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#authentication

Comment: I added some more detail -- you're right, simple per-user is in the docs. But I don't see how to do it for groups.

Comment: You should edit the question to say more about how your existing collections and documents are organized, and how exactly you want to limit access to them.

Comment: Thanks @DougStevenson -- I apparently missed the section on conditional rules, and being able to make queries ("Access Other Documents"). Looks like I'll need to have a "users" table with group membership info (or vice versa, a "groups" table with uids as keys of a map) and use "if k in group".(https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.Map)